# using shared library with custom file extension with cMake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I working on a C++ application running on Linux. The project uses CMake.

It use a third party shared library. Unfortunately, the third party library doesn't end with .so.
And the CMake command `find_library` can't find the library.

Does anyone now how to force CMake to find libraries with a custom file extension? Or at least, how to configure GCC (through CMake) for linking with the library ending with a custom extension?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` [variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html). From the documentation:

> This specifies what suffixes to add to library names when the
>   find_library() command looks for libraries. On Windows systems this is
>   typically .lib and .dll, meaning that when trying to find the foo
>   library it will look for foo.dll etc.

Adding the custom suffix to it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! it is so easy: I appended the extension to the suffixes variable ```string(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ";.abc")```